# Anyone know what font the "Ethic Investments" logo is using?

Tags: fonts, logo

https://ethic.investments/

Anyone know what font this is? The lowercase is striking, but I can't quite remember where I've seen this...

[image: ethic investments logo]

Comment: Can you please follow the guidelines for font identification questions [shown here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the font Circular.

https://lineto.com/The+Fonts/Font+Categories/Text+Fonts/Circular/